# When registering a new version APK how to do a partial update?

Tags: android, google-play-services, apk-expansion-files

When I register my app and upload it to a new version, I know that users who are already installed download only the updated part.
But when I check it, every time I upgrade, I get updates as much as the full size of my app.
I used one obb file and every time I made a new version, I uploaded a new version code apk, a new obb file.
How to configure apk and obb files and how to register them on the Google Developer Console to download updated parts of existing users?

I want to do the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlQih.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload new or add existing expansion files when uploading a new APK into a draft release.

Go to your Play Console.

Select your app.

On the left menu, click Release management > Manage releases.

Next to the release type you want to update, select Manage.

Select Upload APK.

Under "Use expansion files," select the No expansion file drop-down.

Choose whether you want to upload a new file or attach an existing expansion file.

Click Save draft.

Note: You can't remove expansion files from an existing release. If you no longer want to include an expansion file with your APK, create a new release with a new APK that doesn't have the expansion file(s).

Read official guide [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797)

Comment: By following the guide, the update will work normally, but it will be a full update rather than a partial update.

For example, if you update the 1.0.0 version of the 100MB APK to the 1.0.1 version of 110MB, if you have already installed it, you want the update size to be 10MB in the Google Play Store.